# Display Points as GeoJSON Feature Layer in Esri Map in WebFOCUS

Tags: arcgis-js-api, webfocus

I'm trying to load a feature Layer into an existing Esri Choropleth Map Chart. Unfortunately, the points are not rendered correctly if I pass them with a symbol property to the ESRI JS API (they seem to be rendered correctly if passed without this property, but barely visible, so this is not an option). Some of the points are rendered, but on a wrong place and they disappear after zooming. I also used different settings on the geometryLocateField and geometryDataField but without success sofar.

GeoJSON Feature Layers using Polygons work correctly. I tried different Point Datasets and used different CRS. No error messages in the browser console.

Here is the relevant Part of the Code (placed inside overlayLayers array):

```
{
 "title": "GeojsonEarthquakes",
 "layerType": "featurelayer",
 "geometrySourceType": "geojson",
 "symbol": {
          "type": "esriSMS",
            "style": "esriSMSSquare",
            "angle": 0,
            "size": 10,
            "xoffset": 0,
            "yoffset": 0,
            "color": [255,255,0,100],
          "outline": {
            "color": [0,0,0,255],
            "width": 1,
            "type": "esriSLS",
            "style": "esriSLSSolid"
          }
        },
 "geometryLocateField": ["region"],
 "geometryDataField": "name",
 "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/altwitt/0ca2ca03cf060190feddbe511caf1491/raw/5190f1c58f998708c06a600241281d866e4755dc/Volcanoes.geojson"
 },
```

I'm using WebFOCUS 8.2, SP 0.3

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to test the code on a development server running a newer version of WebFOCUS (8.2 SP 0.7) and could not repoduce the error. My suspicion is that this behavior was a bug and has been fixed in a newer Version.